# Opencv remove/replace custom color in image

Tags: opencv

I would like to remove orange color in a colored image using opencv 3 and java.

`Mat src = new Mat();
    src = Imgcodecs.imread("coloredimage.jpg",Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);`

how to select and remove orange color component in my src (original) image ?

If i can not remove the orange color, how can i replace it with transparent color ?

thank

Comment: I describe a technique here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/31277452/2836621

Comment: this technique is usefull but i cannot applied in my android application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach:

- Use inRange() function to filter the orange color. Obtain a binary image such that the orange part is 0 and the remaining part is 1. An example would be:
  `inRange(src, Scalar(0,50,100),Scalar(100,200,250),other_params);`

  (This is a basic preliminary orange color filter. You can refine your values)
- You now have 2 Mat objects - your source image `src` and the mask `mask`. You can now use the following algorithm:

  `result=mask-src;
    result=mask-result;`

This will ensure that the non 0 parts of your `mask` retain their original RGB value in `result`. You can use subtract() function to do the same. Ensure that `mask` has been converted to a 3 channel image beforehand.